# error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module react-native-gesture-handler

Tags: react-native

I keep getting the error when using `react-navigation`. I have tried clearing the cache and reinstalling the node modules but it still does not work.

Comment: What is your `react-native` version? Maybe 0.60?
And this issue occurred on iPhone?

Comment: Can you post your `package.json`?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.6"
  },

Comment: iphone issue as well

Comment: Iphone issue meaning you get this only on iphone?

Comment: get the issue on both android and iphone

Comment: Well, when I faced this issue on iPhone, I used command `pod install` in `ios` folder via terminal.
Then I fixed this issue on iPhone.

Comment: By the way, did you link this module by using `react-native link react-native-gesture-handler`?

Comment: Got it working now